# Using Bundling (from Systelm.Web.Optimization) in ASP.Net WebForms causes issue

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I am trying to put in some *optimization* into my application by using `BundlesCollection` in my `ASP.Net 4.0` application.

My style bundle contains 6 css files. The files are included into a master page. If I remove the CSS files from master page and instead put following:

```
<%= Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/default") %>
```

I am getting following error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code 
    blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Comment: There's a control for rendering bundles in webforms, just get the webforms optimization package from nuget: <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

start the code block with `<%#`  instead of `<%=`

Comment: you rocks, worked like a charm!!!